# How to calculate difference of measures between groups considering the date

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm struggling on how can I calculate the difference between the first and last value, arranged by date, by groups. Here is a toy example:

```
  test1 = data.frame(my_groups = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C",  "A", "A", "A"),
                     measure = c(10, 20, 5, 64, 2, 62 ,2, 5, 4, 6, 7, 105),
                     #distance = c(),
                     time= as.Date(c("20-09-2020", "25-09-2020", "19-09-2020", "20-05-2020", "20-05-2020", "20-06-2021", 
                             "11-01-2021", "13-01-2021", "13-01-2021", "15-01-2021", "15-01-2021", "19-01-2021"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"))
  
  # test1 %>% arrange(my_groups, time)
  #    my_groups measure       time
  # 1          A       5 2020-09-19
  # 2          A      10 2020-09-20
  # 3          A      20 2020-09-25
  # 4          A       6 2021-01-15
  # 5          A       7 2021-01-15
  # 6          A     105 2021-01-19
  # 7          B      64 2020-05-20
  # 8          B       2 2020-05-20
  # 9          B      62 2021-06-20
  # 10         C       2 2021-01-11
  # 11         C       5 2021-01-13
  # 12         C       1 2021-01-13

#desired result
  #    my_groups    diff            
  # 1          A     100 (105 - 5)
  # 2          B       2 (64 - 62)
  # 3          C       1 (1 - 2)
```

The equation inside the brackets in `desired result` is just to show where the `diff` came from.

Any hint on how can I do that?

Comment: shouldn't A be 105-5 = 100 ?

Comment: and C 1 - 2 = -1 ?

Comment: Also.. how would you approch a tie as in C?

Comment: For ties I'll take the min measure. For this I thought of arrange the dataframe first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample data in `data.frame` does not match your console output, so results will be different.

Two methods, depending on a few factors.

1. Assuming that order is externally controlled,

   ```r
   test1 %>%
     group_by(my_groups) %>%
     slice(c(1, n())) %>%
     summarize(diff = diff(measure))
   # # A tibble: 3 x 2
   #   my_groups  diff
   #   <chr>     <dbl>
   # 1 A            95
   # 2 B            -2
   # 3 C             2
   ```

   or just

   ```r
   test1 %>%
     group_by(my_groups) %>%
     summarize(diff = measure[n()] - measure[1])
   ```

   The advantage of this is that it counters an issue with approach 2 below (ties in `which.max`): if you control the ordering yourself, you are guaranteed to use the first/last values you need.

   **NOTE** that for this portion, I assume that the order of data you gave us in your sample data is relevant. I'm assuming that there is some way to guarantee that your results are found. With your latest comment, we can `arrange` before the summarization and get closer to your desired results with

   ```r
   test1 %>%
     arrange(time, -measure) %>%      # this is the "external" sorting I mentioned, so we don't need which.min/.max
     group_by(my_groups) %>%
     summarize(diff = measure[n()] - measure[1])
   # # A tibble: 3 x 2
   #   my_groups  diff
   #   <chr>     <dbl>
   # 1 A           100
   # 2 B            -2
   # 3 C             2
   ```
2. Without pre-sorting, we can use `which.min` and `which.max`. The problem with this is that when ties occur, it may not choose the one that you want.

   ```r
   test1 %>%
     group_by(my_groups) %>%
     summarize(diff = measure[which.max(time)] - measure[which.min(time)])
   # # A tibble: 3 x 2
   #   my_groups  diff
   #   <chr>     <dbl>
   # 1 A           100
   # 2 B            -2
   # 3 C             3
   ```

Comment: OP should clarify how to handle a tie. Your solutions return two different output for C. [however, I dont understand why you have two different values for A]

Comment: Edited for clarity. Further, the OP should clarify why their expected results are inconsistent with their sample data (which is inconsistent with their console output of the sample data).

Comment: works for me! Thank you, @r2evans!

Comment: @Edo, for the record, I am not fond of the fact that the different methods here all produce different results. We cannot control the data, we can only work on assumptions and hopefully capture them clearly. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 0):

```
test1 %>%
    dplyr::group_by(my_groups) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
        first = min(time), last = max(time),
    ) %>% 
    dplyr::select(-time, -measure) %>%
    dplyr::distinct() %>%
    dplyr::mutate(diff = first - last) %>%
    dplyr::select(-first, -last)
```

Comment: this approach returned the difference of dates